# Layout display Issue using Android TabHost

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

[image]

I am working on an application where i have to use android tabhost. I am facing a problem using it, as layout of my activity does not show up properly under the tab. The layout of the activity shows up only in the upper half of the emulator screen and bottom half remain black, while when i saw its xml in design view it depicts the required design.

xml is added below as myscreen.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@color/gray"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_twitter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/twitter_login_unpressed" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_separator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30px"
        android:background="@color/gray" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_login_unpressed" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the relevant activity just contains the following code in onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e("Now", "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myscreen);
```

}

i am unable to figure out why the whole layout under the tab is not shown properly, and tabActivity just has and intent to this activity, there is nothing complex in there...It contains the following code:

public class InfoTabActivity extends TabActivity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.infotablayout);
    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, myActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.today_unpressed)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);



    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

}

What can possibly be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

infotablayout.xml contains this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45px" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: and please post your infotablayout.xml.

Comment: @Hiral...that is also added...!!!

Comment: have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project? and try making layout_height="wrap_content" of your TabWidget in xml,instead of 45px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely in your `infotablayout.xml` - the `FrameLayout` you use for `TabContent` most likely has the attribute `layout_height="wrap_content"`. (Maybe you could post that xml-file too, so we can have a look).

**Edit**

The `LinearLayout` that holds your `TabWidget` and the `FrameLayout` has its height set to `wrap_content` which is why your layout wraps.

---

Little off topic, but you should be able to reduce your `myscreen.xml` file to the following:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@color/gray"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
 android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_twitter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/twitter_login_unpressed"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_login_unpressed"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Kasper....u r right but that was just to see how things happen if i include another linear layout in that....i have added tablayout...check that out...!!!!

Comment: The `LinearLayout` that holds your `TabWidget` and the `FrameLayout` has its height set to `wrap_content` which is why your layout wraps.